# Adding superuser to ASP.NET API that includes same permissions as a regular user

Tags: c#, .net, controller, roles, api-design

I have an ASP.NET MVC API that serves both regular users and admin users. Admin users can do everything regular users can do plus additional functionality.

The HttpContext of requests stores user info which indicates the role of a user. Some endpoints are for use by admin users only. All other endpoints are accessible by all users. Currently, a single controller is being used for both types of user with permissions being used to restrict access accordingly.

However, I'm unsure if this is a good approach because a permission could mistakenly be assigned to the wrong role, or a developer may check the wrong permission for a new endpoint that should be for admin users only.

So, I'm considering two solutions to separate the concerns:

1. Add a Boolean attribute (e.g., `IsAdminUseOnly`) to the endpoints. This seems like a quick decision, but would cause code pollution as every endpoint that is for admin use would require `true` to be specified in the endpoint decorator.
2. Create a subclass "admin" controller that derives from the regular user controller (in a similar way to described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72176089/197591)). The parent and child controllers would effectively each have a different `Route` (e.g., `MyController` and `MyAdminController`). The child (admin) controller would inherit all endpoints from the parent controller. Of course, role access would be specified in the child controller as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42380461/197591) using `[Authorize(Roles = RolesConvention.Administrator)]` for example.

Would either of the above be a suitable solution for this problem, or are there other more suitable methods to achieve the SoC described above?

Comment: Looks like you need role claims added to the user identity; then, just `[Authorize("roles")]` should do its thing.

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using?